# Search Interface

Tags: search

In the page layout, the left panel serves as a menu with a list of teams, while the right panel displays a corresponding list of members and their roles. The first item on the team list is selected by default when you land on the page. The left panel has a progressive search bar designed specifically for team searches. When a search yields no results, the message 'No results found' is displayed on the left panel beneath the search field. However, the question of what content should be presented on the right panel comes in this situation. Should the right panel continue to display information on the previously selected team, or should it also say 'No results found'?"

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the latter — continue to show the previously displayed team's data on the right side. I would add the team name to the right panel, too, so that the user is clear about the context.

Switching both panels to "no results found" seems to be a more confusing choice.

More generally, is there a way to consolidate both panels into a single one? This centralizes the search operation, allows users the flexibility of search teams or team members in a single search bar — based on the assumption that some users will know the team member, but may be unsure of the team they belong to.